# -> What does this mean in php? $blabla->blabla

Tags: php

$blabla->blab, just wondering what this means something to do with an object going into another?

Sorry for being a bit vague .

Comment: That is the syntax to access an objects properties/methods.

Comment: That would access an object value

Answer (score 0):

The arrow-like symbol has nothing to do with "an object going into another".

1. The syntax `$blabla->blab` means a call to attribute `$blab` in the object `$blabla`.
2. The syntax `$blabla->blab()` means a call to method `blab()` in the object `$blabla`.

Please read [the Basics](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php) in PHP documentations.